# Pandas - format csv file adding names to columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've downloaded a dataset (`.data`) from a machine learning repository and saved it as a `cvs` file. then I read it using `pandas`:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('mileage.csv')
```

which prints like so:

[image]

but now I need to add (named) `columns` to the data, which I tried to do with:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('mileage.csv', names=["mpg", "cylinders", "displacement", "horsepower", "weight", "acceleration", "model year", "origin", "car name"])
```

this, however, prints:

[image]

and all data was squeezed into one column...

should I add 'commas' to `cvs` data first?

how do I preprocess this data correctly, each data for each column?

Comment: check out the `sep` argument for `pd.read_csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `assign` to initialize new columns.  It appears that some of the columns are already in the original data, so I'll use a conditional dictionary comprehension to only get the new ones.

```
new_cols = ["mpg", "cylinders", "displacement", "horsepower", "weight", "acceleration", "model year", "origin", "car name"]

dataset = pd.read_csv('mileage.csv')
dataset = dataset.assign(**{c: None for c in new_cols if c not in dataset})
```

Accessing some sample data directly:

```
import urllib2

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chrisjameskirkham/car-mpg/master/auto-mpg-nameless.csv'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
dataset = pd.read_csv(response).assign(**{c: None for c in new_cols if c not in dataset})
```

Comment: error persists...columns are created, but all data is squeezed under `mpg` column...

Comment: Perhaps the file is not comma separated.

Comment: yes, I've pointed that, is there a way of separating it with commas  prior to reading it?

Comment: The point is that the file does not appear to be separated by commas.  Try tabs:  `pd.read_csv('mileage.csv', sep='\t')`